# How can I remove an entry from a map and reorder the entries via key value?

Tags: java

This is a little program I've been working on that tracks some money gains/losses in transactions.

I've basically finished it aside from this problem I have.

```
deleteItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Map<Integer, Entry> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + 1);
                entryTable.removeEntry(table.getSelectedRow() + 1);
                entries.remove(table.getSelectedRow() + 1);

            }

            for(Map.Entry<Integer, Entry> entry : entries.entrySet()) {
                newMap.put(entry.getKey() - 1 == 1 ? 2 : entry.getKey() - 1, entry.getValue());
            }

            if (table.getRowCount() == 1) {
                Gui.this.saveAll();
            }
            entries = newMap;
            Gui.this.saveAll();
        }
    });
```

So this map gets put into a table and if I remove any entry but the first, all works fine. However, if I remove the first entry it removes, but the table doesn't resort itself and I've come to the conclusion it must be the map ordering.

Is there a way I can take the values of the map after an entry is removed and reorder them via their key value so that they remain in numerical order?

Comment: Might look into [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Comment: Use a `TreeMap`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `LinkedHashMap` for your problem is that it retains **insertion** order, not sorting by the actual keys.

Rather than storing the map entries in order, I'd recommend having your UI sort the entries when they're being displayed rather than when storing them. Imagine changing 100 map entries - the map would have to be sorted 100 times in the worst case possible, which is just unnecessary if you display it only once (it is very likely that you change the map more often than displaying/refreshing it).

Going with @jaredr's suggestion though, if you absolutely have to retain key order, have a look at [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Comment: Hmm, so I don't think its my map that is causing the issue. I think it falls down to the table.

I save the data through JSON and if the entry is 2 and not 1, the table shows a null row, but if you go into the JSON file and change the 2 to a 1, it shows properly.

I know the map sorting should fix it, but how should I approach sorting it every time I put in a new entry/row?

Comment: @StuartPerera This sounds more like a flaw in the logic you're doing with the ternary operator and `table.getSelectedRow() != -1` etc. to me, but we'd have to see more of the surrounding code to tell for sure.

Comment: @StuartPerera I'm not quite sure if you've understood me yet; even if this came down to the table logic, **you should not be sorting the map after updating it**. Instead, you should have the UI sort the table for you. A concrete implementation comes down to which window/UI toolkit you use. Again, we'd have to see more of your code to point to a solution.

Comment: I prefer to keep the code private, but oh well. https://hastebin.com/fipozujuti.java is my code. Still missing something here...